# How Image Processing Applications identify the file which user opened?

Tags: design-patterns, ooad, oop

How Image Processing Applications identify the file which user opened?

As we already known Image Processing applications can open all known formats of Images. My question is, How image processing applications know, what kind of file it is opening. It will know from the file extension or It will open the file in binary and read the header of the file and then it i will create object of that File type.

Or any known methods of finding out the image file formats.

For above problem, how you design your system. Which are design patterns you will use.

Thanks in advance.

Harsha

Answer (score 1):

I would have said the design pattern of the application overall is completely unrelated to the process of image format recognition.

Each image file format has binary information very early on which indicate the type of file it is, which is the 'header' of the file.

GIF files, for example, begin with the letters GIF, and a code to indicate which version of the GIF specification, 87a or 89a. PNG files - as Robert Harvey indicates - have a special character, followed by PNG as the first four bytes of the file.

Most of the Wikipedia entries for the major image formats do explain the header, and a bit more about the file itself - in addition to the links above which cover PNG and JPEG, there's also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#File_format for GIFs.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I have a file with the .PNG extension, and I'm not sure that it really is a PNG file.  I can [look at the header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header) and verify that it is a PNG file.

For JPG's I can look at the [syntax and structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure) of the file, and see if it is what I would expect from a JPG.

Generally speaking, the algorithm is: Assume that the image file is the format that the file extension says it is, until the internal structure of the file proves that the extension is wrong.